# How to insert events into an XML::SAX::Pipeline

Tags: perl, filter, insert, sax

I have a SAX filter that wants to insert some content into the current stream for downstream handlers to process (ie: add a node to the output). How can this be accomplished? I was thinking maybe I could instantiate a new pipeline (connected to `$self`) and call `parse_string()` on it but that didn't work:

```
Trying to pop context without push context at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/XML/NamespaceSupport.pm
```

The handler looks something like this:

```
package My::Filter;
use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);

sub end_element {
  my $self = shift;

  if($insertStuff) {
    # WHAT TO DO HERE? 
    # This doesn't work
    XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser( Handler => $self)->parse_string("<new>content</new>");
  }

  $self->SUPER::start_element($element); 
}
```